# The inf and sup of sets

Tags: real-analysis

Do the following identitities hold:
Inf(S+T)=inf(S)+inf(T), where S and T are sets of nonnegative real numbers
Also sup(S+T)=sup(S)+sup(T)

Comment: I am trying to prove that the sum of two regular Borel measures is a regular Borel measure and if the above identities are true, so the regularity is proved.

Comment: What does $S + U$ mean? Set union, $\{x + y \colon x \in S \wedge y \in U\}$, something else?

Comment: @TuckerRapu: I'd say your linked question is not a duplicate; for _sets_ the sup of the sum is equal to the sum of the sups, while for _functions_ there's generally an inequality.

Comment: @user86418  thanks. are you referring to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/703040/85079

Comment: @TuckerRapu: No, that's not the post I meant. I _may_ have meant the post for which this question is now marked as a duplicate (incorrectly, in my opinion), but there are so many variants scattered about the site that it's difficult to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

It's true: Let $m = \inf \{S+T\}$. i.e.

$$m = \inf_{s \in S, t \in T}s + t $$

which implies that for $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists s \in S, t \in T$ s.t

$$m \leq s + t \leq  m + \epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow \inf_{s \in S} s +t \leq  m + \epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow \inf_{s \in S} s +\inf_{t \in T}t \leq  m + \epsilon$$

As $\epsilon$ is arbitrary now, we have 
$$\Rightarrow \inf_{s \in S} s +\inf_{t \in T}t \leq  m $$

Now for the reverse, let $m_1 = \inf_{s \in S} s$, $m_2 = \inf_{t \in T} t$

Then by similar arguments, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists s \in S, t \in T$ s.t
$$ s \leq m_1 + \epsilon/2, t \leq m_2 + \epsilon/2$$

$$\Rightarrow s+t \leq m_1 + m_2 + \epsilon$$

$$\Rightarrow \inf_{s \in S, t \in T}s + t \leq m_1 + m_2 + \epsilon$$
Take $\epsilon$ to 0 to get the reverse.
QED

Comment: This doesn't address the possibility that $S$ or $T$ may be unbounded above (though that case is easily dealt with).

Comment: One way would be to take a bounded subset from each and claim that infimum of the whole set is in the bounded set.

Comment: Oh, there's no problem for the infimum, since $S$ and $T$ are certainly both bounded *below* by $0$. I mean that we need to address the possibility of unboundedness above when finding the supremum. We can't just swap $\inf$ for $\sup$ and turn inequalities around.

Comment: I agree, but as you said, a minor technicality. Let the OP decide if more clarification is needed.